# Interactive Brokers Java API

Tags: java, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

If I want to use the Interactive Brokers Java API to check current positions, and then rebalance those positions, by selling or buying shares of each position, do I just need to use the EWrapper.position() method to get the current positions in the account? Or do I use the EClientSocket.reqPositions() method to get it?

It seems that Ewrapper is for receiving information from TWS to the client, while EClientSocket is for sending requests to TWS. In this case, do I use both position() and reqPosition() methods?

In addition, when I am running the new Java class, do I need to put it in the same folder as the ib.client in order to inherit the other classes and methods?

Answer (score 4):

> It seems that Ewrapper is for receiving information from TWS to the
>   client, while EClientSocket is for sending requests to TWS. In this
>   case, do I use both position() and reqPosition() methods?

That's right.  It's asynchronous so you make a request and hope that sometime soon, you'll get an answer.  All requests go through the socket and all replies come through the wrapper.

> In addition, when I am running the new Java class, do I need to put it
>   in the same folder as the ib.client in order to inherit the other
>   classes and methods?

This is very basic java and it's best if you do some tutorials from somewhere.  In order to use the ib.client methods you import them into your file.  eg. At the top of a file that needs to use this package you can put `import com.ib.client.*` and then make sure the files are in a folder in your source directory like src/com/ib/client/*.java

Or you can make it into a library and include the library in you project.